# Webpage fails to load css file after declaring <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, css

I am using JSP to create a webpage. I have linked the css file to the jsp page with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_mobile.css" type="text/css">`, which is the exact path of the file.

Google Chrome's inspect:

[image]

The content of `<head>` tag in my .jsp file:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

<!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<!-- Include the compiled Ratchet CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ratchet.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_mobile.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablesaw.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fusioncharts-suite-xt/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesaw.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesaw-init.js"></script>

<title>Mobile</title>
</head>
```

CSS files:

[ratches.css](https://jsfiddle.net/fx918ua7/1/)

[style_mobile.css](https://jsfiddle.net/9b36faLq/)

[tablesaw.css](https://jsfiddle.net/mhk45z03/)

The webpage just does not load the css content. Please help.

Comment: Is there any caution output in the console about it not finding the file?

Comment: Yes. I got this warning: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://10.xx.xxx.xx:1234/bscs3_os/mobile/css/style_mobile.css". Is this the cause?? Other than that, no error on the css file not found.

Comment: Yes, this would be the issue

Comment: I solved the warning by changing text/css to text/html. Well, css content still fails to load.

Comment: To confirm, is the location of the stylesheet located following this directory train? bscs3_os/mobile/css/style_mobile.css"

Comment: The directory should be correct. Fyi, the full path is C:\jdev1012\jdev\mywork\bscs3_os\bscs3_os\public_html\mobile\css

Comment: Wait. If I changed the text/css to text/html, the webpage does not load the css content even without declaring doctype html.

Comment: Change it back to the css then, I looked up some articles and it said it should "work" with it --but that may be causing issues. In which files are the classes you are talking about?

Comment: Also, if you go into Google's dev tools -> source you can see which css files it is retrieving/if it isn't getting it

Comment: The three css files - ratchet, style_mobile and tablesaw.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the CSS files? If the classes aren't being defined I feel like something is wrong with how you are selecting it. Remeber that classes in css start with a .

Comment: I don't know why SO asks me to indent the link. Can you please click the edit button under my post and click the link, [2], [3] and [4]? Thanks.

Comment: D'oh! Try closing off your link tags.

Comment: If closing the tags off worked, please tell me and I'll create an answer for the record

Comment: Nope, problem still exists by closing tags off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solve my problem with inline css, although this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

On your developer tool go to -> Network tab. And Select ->  CSS. Reload the page. You will see the list of css files included on your DOM along with its status. From here you can from where the files are loading. If not loading you will find them as red marked with 404 status. 
You have to make sure the relative path you used and the directory of the css files are same location.

Comment: We already discussed this in the comments and ruled it out, thanks for trying to help, though! :)

Comment: I have checked what you mentioned. There is no error at the network tab. Hmm.

Comment: @Brian So that might be an jsp issue.